# Form Validation not working - javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, web

I am trying to implement form validation so that when the submit button is hit, all required fields are filled.
here is my code:

```
function checkInput()
{
    <!--check if these input values are provided -->
    var inputFile = document.getElementByID('inputFile').value;
    var numThreads = document.getElementById('numThreads').value;
    var scoreThresh = document.getElementById('scoreThresh').value;
    var scorePen = document.getElementById('scorePenalty').value;

    if(inputFile==="" ||numThreads==="" ||scoreThresh==="" ||scorePen==="" )
    {
        alert('Please fill in all required fields');

    }
```

//how i decalare the form

```
 <form  method =POST id="weVoteForm" onsubmit="return checkInput()">
```

this code isnt working however. Can anyone clarify what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use the `required` attributes on the form fields? All modern browsers support this.

Comment: why the POST is added witout quotes?

Comment: check `var inputFile = document.getElementById('inputFile').value;` it's a typo..`ID` is not a caps..use `d` with small letter.And use `return false` in end of the `checkinput()` function.

Comment: In JavaScript you cannot use `<!--` to make comments. You should use `//`.  Also as pointed by @prasad you should use `Id` instead of `ID` and the `POST` was quoted because in HTML you put values inside quotes

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `checkInput` function before submitting the form.
For this you can use `onsubmit` event in the form element as.

```
<form method="POST" id="weVoteForm" onsubmit="return checkInput();">
</form>
```

Your function should look like this

```
function checkInput()
{

    //check if these input values are provided -->
    // notice not <!-- in JS for comment and Id not ID
    var inputFile = document.getElementById('inputFile').value;
    var numThreads = document.getElementById('numThreads').value;
    var scoreThresh = document.getElementById('scoreThresh').value;
    var scorePen = document.getElementById('scorePenalty').value;

    if(inputFile==="" ||numThreads==="" ||scoreThresh==="" ||scorePen==="" )
    {
        alert('Please fill in all required fields');
        return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

Moreover you can set required attribute in each element without having you to write this code as.

```
<input type="text" required />
```

Comment: you are wrong. _checkInput(); return false;_ will return always wrong

Comment: You are right but his function is not returning anything so I was just assuring him that the function needs to be called.